# How I can remove the pages from in "inurl" inurl:example.com

Tags: wordpress, web-scraping, search, seo, google-search-console

I'm encountering an issue where certain pages from my domain are appearing in search results when using the "inurl" operator to limit the search to my domain (e.g., inurl:example.com). However, I want to exclude specific pages from these search results. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this? Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I attempted to refine my search on Google using the "inurl" operator to limit results to my domain. I expected to see only pages from my domain in the search results. However, certain unwanted pages from my domain still appeared in the results.

Comment: Add these URLs to the robots.txt file.

Comment: @ShubhamVerma These pages are set to no-index and blocked in the robots.txt file. We are not receiving traffic from Google search results. However, when searching using "inurl", all pages are displayed.

Comment: @ZehadKhan If I understand you correctly, you have both meta robots and robots.txt limit set. If that's the case, then that's why the more efficient restriction (meta robots) doesn't work because robots.txt ignores it. You can check this in the Google documentation: [Combining robots.txt rules with indexing and serving rules](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag#combining)

Comment: @ShubhamVerma
However, these pages are no longer hosted on our server. Despite removing all pages from the site, Google continues to index them. Whenever I search on Google using this parameter, all pages from the old domain with their titles are visible. These pages are no longer in use, as we have migrated to a new domain.

[Our Site pages link on google](https://t.ly/b8w8z)